# Unhandled exception in ToString overload

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Hallo and thanks for your time.

I have recently decided to try using Xamarin.Android, to develop an idea I had.

However, I've run into the weirdest problem I've ever had.

```
public class Note : INote
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public List<ITag> Tags { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        try
        {
            const int maxLength = 20;
            if (Content.Length > maxLength)
            {
                return Content.Substring(0, maxLength - 1);
            }
            return Content;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Content;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above class, when I do a ToString operation on a note object with less than 20 chars in it, I get an unhandled exception. Which I thought was quite weird, so I wrapped the part with the substring in a try/catch.

However, I still get an unhandled exception. How can this be?

[image: Unhandled Exception - ArgumentOutOfRangeException]

EDIT:
The exception window also looks werid. Normally they look like this.
[image: Intentional exception]

The ToString are being called when populating a ListView, which is done in this piece of code.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/ApplicationName")]
public class ShowNotesActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ShowNotes);
        var persistence = new Persistence();
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<INote>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, persistence.GetAllNotes());

        listView.Adapter = adapter;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the input in when you got the exception?

Comment: So you are saying that when `Content` is of less than 20 characters, then also it is going inside of `if` condition? if yes, can you put breakpoint on `if` condition and check exact value of `Content.Length` at that time.

Comment: If Content.Length is lower than 20, I get the exception. It could be anything. Last fix I tried, I had created two notes. One with the content of: "asdfghjklqwertyuiopz", which didn't cause any exception. And one with Content of: "e" which did cause an exception

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside `ToString()` and watched the exception happen at the place you expect it to be? Because there does not seem to be a stack trace...

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari It just crashes. If I put a breakpoint on ToString, it crashes as soon as I "step into" the method

Comment: @MortenToudahl try putting logs, I doubt if `Content` property is being set properly while `ToString()`

Comment: @AmitMaheshwari Im afraid I don't know what you mean by "try putting logs". I have however verified that both Content and its property Length contains values.

Comment: @MortenToudahl Are you stepping into the function in Debug build mode?

Comment: @xinux I am, yes.

Comment: I've run your code in Visual Studio and confirms that it works with strings of length 0 through 40 without any exceptions being thrown. I will say, however, that you don't have any handling of `null` (outside of an extraneous try-catch, anyway).

Comment: @MortenToudahl You say you put a breakpoint _on_ ToString, have you tried putting it _in_ ToString? Keep in mind ToString is called every time the object is displayed in the debugger.

Comment: @xinux I believe I have. One moment, let me verify.

Comment: @xinux That is even more odd. None of the breakpoints placed inside ToString are hit. Only the one on the starting curly bracket of the method.

Comment: @Abion47 So it works without problems? Then it must be my IDE. Thank you for pointing out that I'm not checking for null. I'm intentionally doing a crude implementation while trying to learn Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @Abion47 Could you please post an answer? It would seem that it is indeed my IDE that is causing it. I have now removed the ToString method, and I am still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I tested in Visual Studio and confirmed that it works:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Content == null)
            return null;

        const int maxLength = 20;
        if (Content.Length > maxLength)
            return Content.Substring(0, maxLength - 1);

        return Content;
    }
}
```

Here is what I used to test it (The utility method being one of my own methods from my code sandbox):

```
var card = new Card();
var str = Utility.GetRandomAlphaNumString(40);

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    card.Content = str.Substring(0, i);
    Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
}
```

Here is what it printed:

```
// [Empty result]
W
W1
W1U
W1UJ
W1UJ2
W1UJ2X
W1UJ2X4
W1UJ2X48
W1UJ2X48B
W1UJ2X48BU
W1UJ2X48BU9
W1UJ2X48BU9A
W1UJ2X48BU9A4
W1UJ2X48BU9A46
W1UJ2X48BU9A46C
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CY
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYV
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8R
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
W1UJ2X48BU9A46CYVA8
```

(Note that it didn't actually print "Empty result". I just had to type something there as otherwise SO wouldn't let me start the code block with a line of just spaces.)

Since the above code works just fine, I can say that whatever your problem is, it doesn't have anything to do with the code. (Or, at the very least, *this* code.)

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction. I don't know exactly what happend. But it seems it was a problem in the project. I deleted the project, and copied over all of the code I had written. Now its working fine.